# "Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : cannot open the connection" with RMarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am currently trying to render my `report.Rmd` document with `rmarkdown::render()`.
Whenever I run it, though, I am getting this error:

```
> rmarkdown::render("report.Rmd")


processing file: report.Rmd
  |....                                                                  |   6%
  ordinary text without R code

  |.........                                                             |  12%
label: setup (with options) 
List of 1
 $ include: logi FALSE

Quitting from lines 9-46 (report.Rmd) 
Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : cannot open the connection
```

The chunk in lines 9-46 contains approximately the following:

```
{r setup, include = FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

library(jsonlite)


here::i_am("README.md")

# Set paths up
config <- read_json("config.json")
output_dir <- config$data_output
 
base::load(file.path(output_dir, "file1.rda"))
base::load(file.path(output_dir, "file2.rda"))

[...]
```

I strongly suspect that the issue is in the line with `jsonlite::read_json()`, as this is the first point where I find the issue by commenting out the rest of it (starting from the bottom). The same path in the same `.json` file worked on a previous analysis step, but I am running the file from a project subfolder (as I want the output to be saved on this subfolder too).

Would you be able to help me to figure out a solution? Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Rmarkdown expects all paths to be relative to the directory of the Rmarkdown file itself. Did you double-check that all files are being referenced at the correct relative path?

Comment: I suggest for troubleshooting purposes, you put all the files you need in the same directory as the original .Rmd file, Rmarkdown looks in it's current directory for the files and it can get messy if you are using multiple files from different directories.

Comment: @Carey: no, they aren't, this one in particular isn't. As a workaround, do you think I can just put the output files I need in the parent folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error shows up when the path does not have the exact file specified in the argument.

The command `here::i_am()` (and the package `here` in general) does not change the main path R is working with (i.e. in `getwd()`), it just simplifies calling any `file` from the main folder by using `here("file")` instead of stating the full path in the argument (e.g., `"./path/to/file"`).

In this case, the correct argument would be `read_json(here::here("config.json"))`